# rational representation of semisimple algebraic group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a connected semisimple algebraic group defined over $\mathbb Q$. Could some expert give me a complete classification  of  finite dimensional $\mathbb Q$-irreducible representations of $G$?
If convenient please feel free  to assume that $G$ is almost simple or simply connected.

Basically what I want to know is the following: given an irreducible representation over $\mathbb C$, is it possible to give a list of all the $\mathbb Q$ irreducible representations whose irreducible component over $\mathbb C$ is the given one. I feel it is possible to do so in the case where $G=SL_n$.

It might be possible find the answer in the  Borel-Tits 1965 IHES paper, but it is in French which I can not read.

It seems that the question is difficult to answer, so probably it is helpful to restrict to the cases which I really need. Assume $G$ has 
no $\mathbb Q$-anisotropic factors and the irreducible component over $\mathbb C$ is Minuscule (maybe I should say the corresponding Lie algebraic representation is Minuscule).

Comment: This might be a bit ambitious for arbitrary $G$. Also, even over $\mathbb{C}$, the answer of "by dominant integral weights" may not be a satisfactory classification. It perhaps does not portend well for a classification over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @ Peter Crooks: over $\mathbb C$, the classification by dominant integral weights is satisfied.

Comment: I have a couple of lists: Restriction of scalars from an absolutely (over $\mathbb C$) irreducible representation over a number field, representations in $GL_n( D)$ where $D$ is a central division algebra over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Basically what I want to know is the following: given an irreducible representation over $\mathbb C$, is it possible to give a list of all the $\mathbb Q$ irreducible representations whose irreducible component  over $\mathbb C$ is the given one. I feel it is possible to do so in the case where $G=SL_n$.

Comment: Right, over $\mathbb{C}$, this is the answer. I was unsure about whether such an answer was a satisfactory classification for your purposes. Anyway, I would suggest editing your post to take into account the comment you have just made. I think it will help yield the sort of answer you seek.

Comment: @ronggang: Even though you want to avoid papers in French, I should point to the standard one by Tits http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002185725&IDDOC=262152,  which tries to look comprehensively at the problem (over an arbitrary field of definition, but almost as complicated over $\mathbb{Q}$).   Keep in mind that the $\mathbb{Q}$-anisotropic case is always lurking in the background.

Comment: So you're not trying to descend an irreducible representation of $G_{\mathbf{C}}$ over $\mathbf{C}$ to one of $G$ over $\mathbf{Q}$? Note that if $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional rational representations of an affine group scheme $G$ of finite type over an infinite field $k$ and if $K/k$ is any extension field then inside the affine space $H={\rm{Hom}}(V,W)^G$ of $G$-equivariant maps the locus $I$ of isomorphisms is Zariski-open (perhaps empty...), so $I(k)$ is non-empty if and only if $I(K)$ is non-empty; that may remove some ambiguity of descent.

Comment: @ user74230: I don't understand your method of descend. What information can we get from this construction?

Comment: @ronggang: What I am saying is that for the *given*  $\mathbf{Q}$-group $G$ and an irreducible $\mathbf{C}$-linear algebraic representation $V$ of $G_{\mathbf{C}}$, up to isomorphism there is *at most one* $\mathbf{Q}$-linear representation $V_0$ of $G$ recovering $V$ after scalar extension to $\mathbf{C}$. I am not saying how to characterize which such $V$ admit such a $V_0$ (i.e., what is needed beyond the necessary condition that the character of $V$ comes from a regular function on $G$ over $\mathbf{Q}$), just that $V_0$ is unique up to isomorphism *if* it exists.

Comment: @ronggang: Note that by using highest-weight theory in characteristic 0, any such $V$ does descend to $\mathbf{Q}$ when $G$ is split, and more generally every $V$ descends to a number field that splits $G$. Also, since there are only scalar automorphisms, the obstruction to descent to $\mathbf{Q}$ is a class in the Brauer group ${\rm{Br}}(\mathbf{Q})$ (exactly as when trying to descend the "field of definition" of an absolutely irreducible representation of a finite group in characteristic 0), so by class field theory all obstructions are local. So think about the real and $p$-adic cases.

Comment: @user74230: I see what you mean. Thanks. But unfortunately I am more interested in the $\mathbb Q$ representations which do not come from descending.